# Adding up, multiplying and finding the number with the lowest value in JAVA

Tags: java

Write into a TextField 10 whole numbers like this: 1, 2, 3, .... After you click the + button (which you create) it will do the sum of the numbers in a jLabel, then there is a * button which will multiply all the numbers and print them out in a seperate jLabel, and then there's a Minimum button, which will show the number in the array with the lowest value in yet another seperate jLabel.

Yes, I'm sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I only need to know what is the code for the last part, the MINIMUM part. I tried java.lang.Math_MIN (dunno if it's written right) and I tried the length operator, none of them worked...
Note: It's done in NetBeans, and I'm not from an english speaking country so if i send you the code parts of it are in my language.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. If you show some effort and show us what you've tried and what, in particular, you're stuck with, we'll be much happier to help.

Comment: paste your code please

Comment: Do you need help with the GUI, or with the math code?

Comment: @Pragnani the homework tag is deprecated

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen it seems to be in the right place considering the question :(

Comment: @FlorisVelleman It seems so, yes, but it was decided not to use it any more (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/204841)

Comment: If you can at least show us anything you've tried, even if it's wrong or doesn't work, then we'd be more than happy to help. Otherwise we can't do your work for you.

Comment: This one really astonishes me, as he said that the reason he is asking is because he doesn't want to take the time to do the homework himself... 
This isn't how SO works.

Comment: For the minimum part: if you keep your numbers in a comparable collection, you can use [java.util.Collections#min](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29) to find the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for the sum, the rest should be easy.

```
btnPlus = new JButton("+");
        btnPlus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String nums = textField.getText();

                if (nums.matches("[0-9]+") && nums.length() == 10) {

                    char[] charArray = nums.toCharArray();
                    int sum = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
                        sum += Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
                    }
                    label_1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
                }
            }
```